# Unable to create SQLCipher Database with Password

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I been trying for few hours just to create a simple database with password..

Here's the code.

```
//Activity 1
     SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
                dbPasswordHelper2 = new DatabaseHelper2(this);
                dbPasswordHelper2.insertPassword(password);


//DatabaseHelper2 Class

    public DatabaseHelper2(Context context) {
      super(context, dbName, null, 1);
      this.context = context;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createDBQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +passwordTableName + "("+password+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createDBQuery);

}
public void insertPassword(String passwordKey)
{

    String totalPass = passwordKey + salt;
    System.out.println(totalPass);
            File databaseFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName+".db");
            databaseFile.mkdirs();
            databaseFile.delete();
            SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, key, null);
}
```

The app crashes at the last line of `insertPassword()`:

```
 SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, key, null);
```

I really don't understand what the problem is.. I've been freaking out for hours trying to figure out what the problem is.
Thank you.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare Unable to use LogCat with my device after I burned another ROM :(

Comment: Then I fail to see how you plan on doing any Android development with that device. Perhaps you should switch to the x86 emulator, or buy a replacement device.

Comment: @CommonsWare Alright, thank you. You're right, It is really annoying developing like this.

Comment: I'm sorry my answer sounded like I was yelling at you.  It definitely was not how I felt.  I was truly trying to assist you.

Comment: @HalR It's totally fine, I understand. Plus, I was a little bit angry before I commented your answer, sorry for being rude, I'm sure you were just intending to help me. Have a good day :)